# why it's showig wrong output for prime factors?

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop, factors, prime-factoring

I made this program to find prime factors of a number, but when i am running this code it's giving the wrong output. I have debugged this code and also the logic is correct.
what i found is that, when "x == 1" the the program misbehaves. I am not able to find the answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void prime(int );
main()
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number to find its prime factors: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nPrime factors of %d are: \n", num);

    prime(num);
}

void prime(int x)
{
    int i = 2;

    while(x != 1)
    {
        if(x % i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d, ", i);

            x = x / i;
            prime(x);
        }

        else
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the wrong output? What should be the correct output?

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen 
Eg: input = 20
answer should be = 2,2,5
but it shows = 2,2,5,5,2,5,5

Comment: Has it to be recursive?

Comment: @Bob__ 
i know the logic and i have made program without recursion but i just want to know why it's giving wrong output?
i am not able to find the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should break from your loop once you find the first divisor. Otherwise, your outer method call will continue searching for divisors of your `x` even though it's no longer needed:

```
void prime(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        printf("All prime numbers are prime factors of 0");
        return;
    }

    if (x == INT_MIN) {
        printf("Please provide a number larger than %i", INT_MIN);
        return;
    }

    x = abs(x);
    int i = 2;
    while(x != 1) {
        if(x % i == 0) {
            printf("%d, ", i);

            x = x / i;
            prime(x);
            break; // break here
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

However, recursion is not actually needed here - instead you could use a simple iterative algorithm as below:

```
void prime(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        printf("All prime numbers are prime factors of 0");
        return;
    }

    if (x == INT_MIN) {
        printf("Please provide a number larger than %i", INT_MIN);
        return;
    }

    x = abs(x);
    int i = 2;
    while (x != 1) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            printf("%d, ", i);
            x = x / i;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain it more?
when i wrote prime(x); the loop should break automatically

Comment: @AdityaNaitan each time your method invokes itself again it doesn't terminate - it waits until all the inner invocations are complete and then just continues executing your loop..That's how recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following recursive function as it is shown in the demonstrative program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prime( unsigned int x )
{
    if ( !( x < 2 ) )
    {
        unsigned int i = 2;

        while ( x % i ) ++i;

        printf( "%u, ", i );

        prime( x / i );
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int num;

    printf( "Enter a number to find its prime factors: " );
    scanf( "%u", &num );

    printf( "\nPrime factors of %u are: \n", num );

    prime( num );   

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like:

```
Enter a number to find its prime factors: 10
Prime factors of 10 are: 
2, 5,
```

That is the recursive call of the function should be placed outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

When a recursive approach is chosen, one of the critical steps is to determine the stopping condition.

The (or at least one) problem in the posted code is that the recursive call is made *inside* a `while` loop, so that the prime factors are found and printed *multiple times*.

I'd also avoid to restart the factors search from 2 every time, but in that case you should add a parameter to the recursive function. In the following, I splitted the logic of the prime factorization into two functions, only one of those recursive.

```
void prime_impl(int n, int factor, const char* delim)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return;

    while (factor <= n  &&  n % factor)
        ++factor;

    printf("%s%d", delim, factor);

    prime_impl(n / factor, factor, " * ");
}

void prime_factorization(int n)
{
    printf("%4d", n);
    if ( n < 0 )
        prime_impl(-n, 2, " = ");
    else
        prime_impl(n, 2, " = ");
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LFOiY8XbDD4H301G).

Answer (score -2):

Since the "DEBUG" of the above code is requested, I intend to answer question with the same logic.

1. The loop count variable "i" needs to be a static variable
2. The break condition of the recursion was missing.

Fixed Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void prime(int );
main()
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number to find its prime factors: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nPrime factors of %d are: \n", num);

    prime(num);
}

void prime(int x)
{
    static int i = 2;

    while(x != 1 && i <= x)
    {
        if(x % i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d, ", i);

            x = x / i;
            i++;
            prime(x);
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```